# How to call C# controller method from dojo javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, dojo

I am using esriRequest to call c# action method using following code, but whenever i am calling this code it is going into error handler with 404 error. please help me to get rid of this problem.

```
           requestParam = esriRequest({
            url: "/Home/GetData",
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": null,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            content: {
                param: "reqParam"
            },
            handleAs: "json",
            useProxy: true,
            usePost: false
        });
        requestParam .then(lang.hitch(this, function(response) {                
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }), lang.hitch(this, function(error) {                
            deferred.reject(error);
        }));
        return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of home i need to give my controller class name without Controller key word. if My controller name **"TestController"** then give only **Test/GetData**. Thanx everyone.